# Finding an custom element in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a class in JavaScript like

```
function chat(data){
this.id = data.id;
this.name = data.name;
this.message = data.message
this.date = data.date;
}
```

Now i declare an array like this.

```
     var message = [];
```

and push my chat object in message array;

```
var chat = new chat(data);
message.push(chat);
```

**What is the best possible way to find the elements in message array by id.
Or any thing else which make it easier also i need to short the array using date also.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON - Javascript - How to search array item by searching list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483955/json-javascript-how-to-search-array-item-by-searching-list-of-values)

Comment: for what purpose do you want to use this function.. If you are using it for an application … you can use AngularJS . as it gives filter and sorting functions.. otherwise you can create a function to loop over and check...

Answer (score 0):

Loop. Since chat is an object you cannot use Array.indexOf.

If you instead do

```
var Message = {};
Message[data.id]=new chat(data);
```

If chat() is as simple as you show, then just do

```
Message[data.id]=data;
```

Then you can access either directly by id